# Error response from daemon: Get https://armdocker.rnd.se/v1/_ping: Not Found

Tags: kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes version 1.10.

I am trying to pull an image from a local docker repo. I already have the correct secret created.

```
[root@node1 ~]# kubectl get secret
NAME                   TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
arm-docker        kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1         10m
```

Checking the secret in detail gives me the correct auth token

```
[root@node1 ~]# kubectl get secret arm-docker --output="jsonpath={.data.\.dockerconfigjson}" | base64 -d
{"auths":{"armdocker.rnd.se":{"username":"<MY-USERNAME>","password":"<MY-PASSWORD>","email":"<MY-EMAIL>","auth":"<CORRECT_AUTH_TOKEN>"}}}
```

But when I create a Pod, Im getting the following ERROR :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              13s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned authorization-backend-deployment-8fd5fc8d4-msxvd to node6
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  13s               kubelet, node6     MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-w7vlf"
  Normal   BackOff                4s (x4 over 10s)  kubelet, node6     Back-off pulling image "armdocker.rnd.se/proj/authorization_backend:3.6.15"
  Warning  Failed                 4s (x4 over 10s)  kubelet, node6     Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling                1s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet, node6     pulling image "armdocker.rnd.se/proj/authorization_backend:3.6.15"
  Warning  Failed                 1s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet, node6     Failed to pull image "armdocker.rnd.se/proj/authorization_backend:3.6.15": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://armdocker.rnd.se/v1/_ping: Not Found
  Warning  Failed                 1s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet, node6     Error: ErrImagePull
```

Why is it looking for `/v1/_ping` ? Can I disable this somehow ?

Im unable to understand what is the problem here.

Comment: It's lookin for /v1/_ping to check if the docker registry is available. It does not seem to be. Are you administrator for the registry? is it only available via http maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Once defined your secret, you need to use it inside your pod (you didn't whether you used it).

```
 kind: Pod
 ...
 spec:
   imagePullSecrets:
   - name: arm-docker
```